# AWS S3 - Calculate File Hash with Lambda

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Is it possible to use a lambda function for every PUT request to a S3 bucket to calculate the file hash? And yes, I know, that S3 uses etags.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  What does "the" file hash mean? There are many hashing algorithms. You say you know S3 "uses" Etags... well, the Etag **is** a hash of the file content, using one of two algorithms... so, it isn't clear what you are wanting to do, or why,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can activate S3 Event Notifications for every PUT event. These events can be delivered to a lambda where you can hash the file.

Events can be enabled under the S3 Bucket -> Properties -> Events

There you can check the 'PUT' event type and set the lambda as event receiver.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a trigger for your lambda function.

Configure triggers -> Choose S3 -> Event type -> Object Created PUT

You will get notification for every PUT request on bucket. You can access it using lambda handler and perform hash operation in that handler function.